# Как запустить javah из Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jni, java

Здравствуйте. Не могу запустить javah - не переваривает путь к класс-файлу:

> classpath D:/eclipse/workspace/JNITest/bin/jnitest/jnitest.Caller

При попытке запуска говорит, что ничего не видит:

> Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.

Ось win7 64.
Не могу понять, в чём дело. Пробелов нет, имя класса задано полностью, всё вроде нормально. Но не работает. Кто-нибудь из вас сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так не пробовали?

[How to run Javah from Eclipse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451378/how-to-run-javah-from-eclipse)

Comment: пробовал, ${java_type_name} empty selection пишет. По этой переменной ничего толкового нашёл, в т.ч. в буржуйских интернетах...

Comment: помогла вот такая форма записи:
-classpath . jnitest.Caller
Но вот не понимаю до сих пор, что ему до этого не нравилось и что означает точка после classpath=)

Comment: `-classpath .` - добавляете в класспас текущую директорию